# After deserialization getting null object C# Windows Phone

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, deserialization

I was trying to play with an [API](http://grandtheftdata.com/bawsaq/#api). The API is returning the data in JSON.
Here is my code to make the request

```
private void makerequest()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://grandtheftdata.com/bawsaq/api?a=DATA&o=JSON&p=PS3&t=2014-04-08T15:00:00Z," + now.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD") + "T" + now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "Z") as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        var playerResponse = request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(getPlayer), request);
    }

    private void getPlayer(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            string jsondata;
            HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState; ;
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(ar))
            {
                System.IO.Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    jsondata = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                responseStream.Close();
            }

            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                PS3BAWSAQ.RootObject feed = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PS3BAWSAQ.RootObject>(jsondata);
                MessageBox.Show(jsondata.Length + " characters");
            }
            );
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Do something
        }
    }
```

and the JSON data it is returning in `jsondata` variable is

```
   {
    "data": {
        "PS3": {
            "2014-04-08T15:30:01Z": {
                "AMU": 3.42,
                "BDG": 6.73,
                "BET": 716.1,
                "BFA": 83.58,
                "BIN": 3.82,
                "BLE": 3591.3,
                "BRU": 4.5,
                "BTR": 3.51,
                "CNT": 50.15,
                "CRE": 2.5,
                "DGP": 100.16,
                "EYE": 3.68,
                "FAC": 3.49,
                "FRT": 3.86,
                "GOT": 6.09,
                "HAL": 3.58,
                "HVY": 1.45,
                "LSC": 1551.79,
                "LST": 1045.54,
                "LTD": 336.95,
                "MAI": 348.5,
                "PIS": 2.64,
                "PMP": 2143.31,
                "PON": 1700.82,
                "RON": 323.46,
                "SHK": 7.03,
                "SHR": 1261.47,
                "SHT": 582.65,
                "SPU": 1607.05,
                "SUB": 1509.58,
                "TNK": 5.56,
                "UMA": 4.47,
                "VAP": 6.86,
                "VOM": 1183.48,
                "WAP": 88.74,
                "WIW": 7.16,
                "WIZ": 1.28,
                "WZL": 999.98,
                "ZIT": 3.46
            }
        }
    },
    "status": {
        "code": 200,
        "text": "ok"
    }
}
```

And the classes generated by json2csharp.com are

```
public class __invalid_type__20140324T144502Z
    {
        public double AMU { get; set; }
        public double BDG { get; set; }
        public double BET { get; set; }
        public double BFA { get; set; }
        public double BIN { get; set; }
        public double BLE { get; set; }
        public double BRU { get; set; }
        public double BTR { get; set; }
        public double CNT { get; set; }
        public double CRE { get; set; }
        public double DGP { get; set; }
        public double EYE { get; set; }
        public double FAC { get; set; }
        public double FRT { get; set; }
        public double GOT { get; set; }
        public double HAL { get; set; }
        public double HVY { get; set; }
        public double LSC { get; set; }
        public double LST { get; set; }
        public double LTD { get; set; }
        public double MAI { get; set; }
        public double PIS { get; set; }
        public double PMP { get; set; }
        public double PON { get; set; }
        public double RON { get; set; }
        public double SHK { get; set; }
        public double SHR { get; set; }
        public double SHT { get; set; }
        public double SPU { get; set; }
        public double SUB { get; set; }
        public double TNK { get; set; }
        public double UMA { get; set; }
        public double VAP { get; set; }
        public double VOM { get; set; }
        public double WAP { get; set; }
        public double WIW { get; set; }
        public double WIZ { get; set; }
        public double WZL { get; set; }
        public double ZIT { get; set; }
    }

    public class PS3
    {
        public __invalid_type__20140324T144502Z __invalid_name__2014 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public PS3 PS3 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Status
    {
        public int code { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Data data { get; set; }
        public Status status { get; set; }
    }
```

The thing is I am not able to deserialize the JSON data to PS3BAWSAQ object properly.
[image: result]

And I am sure the problem is in the class name(invalid type). I changed their names but that didn't help either. The JSON has a member which is itself time dependent.

Can't figure a way to solve this. Please help.

Comment: It looks like you have a "key" that is changing its name (as it's really a time stamp: `"2014-04-08T15:30:01Z"`), so you can't deserialize it. You could try to "fix" the results so that the date/time stamp becomes a value. Or you could use something like JSON.NET and leave the JSON document in a more raw form (rather than deserializing into C# objects).

Comment: There should be something that I could do. Isn't there anything? Without deserializing how can I use the data in a ListBox?

Comment: I suggested two things. Trying fixing their data using JSON.NET.

Comment: Would you mind telling my how to 'fix' the data? I do not know much about JSON. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `JsonConvert.Deserialize(string)` method returns a dynamic object.

This is where you create your dynamic object

```
 dynamic x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsondata);
```

Dynamic objects are really nice to work with. You can reference properties that the compiler have no clue exist or not. [You can read about them here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx)

You must parse the dynamic object like this.

Assuming that its only returning one of the above objects in the JSON

```
PS3BAWSAQ.RootObject obj = new PS3BAWSAQ.RootObject (){

   Prop1 = x.Key1,
   Prop2 = x.Key2,
   //And So on

};
```

if its a list of objects you do it like this

```
foreach(PS3BAWSAQ.RootObject y in x){
    PS3BAWSAQ.RootObject obj = new PS3BAWSAQ.RootObject (){

       Prop1 = y.Key1,
       Prop2 = y.Key2,
       //And So on

    };
}
```

if its a list of lists do it like this

```
foreach(var y in x.list1Name){
  foreach(PS3BAWSAQ.RootObject z in y){
    PS3BAWSAQ.RootObject obj = new PS3BAWSAQ.RootObject (){

       Prop1 = z.Key1,
       Prop2 = z.Key2,
       //And So on

    };
  }
}
```

In your case it looks like its a single object being returned. So you would want option one. Just new up a new container and set each property individually. **THE KEYS ARE CASE SENSITIVE!!!**

Comment: I tried your code and it is throwing an exception. Here is the detail 
An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to 'APIractice.PS3BAWSAQ.Data'

Please don't get annoyed. I am a noob working with JSON. This is my first attempt.

Comment: OK. I am getting it a little bit. But I am confused. As you can see, there is a key in the returned JSON which is dependent on time, I really don't know how to access it.

Comment: I have answered your question as much as I can in this format. If you want me to continue helping please do as I asked on twitter and either provide me with your solution at amr@anthonyrussell.info or add your solution to a tfs account and I will log on at fix it.